# Why is current CPU frequency read-only for root?

Tags: linux, cpu, acl, cpu-speed

I have a program that provides benchmarks, but its OS agnostic and does not know how to read CPU frequencies. The test program is driven through a script. If I provide the CPU frequency, then the program can calculate throughput of operations.

I thought I would provide the current CPU frequency (for the most accurate reading), but it appears the value is read-only for root and no access for others:

```
$ ls -Al /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 affected_cpus
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 cpuinfo_cur_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 cpuinfo_max_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 cpuinfo_min_freq
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 scaling_max_freq
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 scaling_min_freq
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 23:19 scaling_setspeed
```

As ***`ls -l`*** shows, ***`cpuinfo_cur_freq`*** is the only object with that particular ACL. The other entries are mostly ***`0444`*** (***`0644`*** for some).

Why is current CPU frequency read-only for root and no access for others?

Comment: does the file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online` exist? if not, then your system doesn't support certain actions on that particular core (some architectures have dependencies on cpu0, so you cannot take it offline, etc). see the yellowbox warning here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-rhel-centos-redhat-suse-hotplug-cpu/#more-3555 . If the permissions are more lenient on cpu1 then it is very likely that the issue is specific to that core.

Comment: @Frank - it appears the file does not exist: ***`cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online: No such file or directory`***.

Comment: then that implies that the core is locked, and the system won't let anyone change it. For the most part the files in /sys/devices/ are barely files, in that they read data from the running state of the box, but don't generally control them.

Comment: Still have the issue? I'm seeing it in Debian stable (stretch), but `sudo chmod a+r` changes permissions ok. Also seeing scaling_cur_freq values randomly bouncing around -+10% or more, while cpuinfo_cur_freq & /proc/cpuinfo & cpufreq_info are all steady & apparently correct.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to read

```
scaling_cur_freq
```

To answer the question:

It seems that reading

```
cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

communicates directly with the hardware or - depending on implementation - the firmware which obviously shouldn't be allowed unprivileged.

[Source](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.cpufreq/7008)

Comment: Thanks @Hydranix. The machine I am testing on has EFI, and not BIOS. The other machines I frequently test on are IoT gadgets, like BananaPi's and BeagleBone's. Some of them are producing incorrect results with ***`scaling_cur_freq`***. For example, my [LeMaker HiKey](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B019O3QTSA) (ARM64), with dual Cortex-A53s (eight cores) running at 1.2 GHz, is producing a value of ***`432000`***. And my [BananaPi Pro](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00RD86QPA), with a Cortext-A7 running at 1 GHz, is producing a value of ***`600000`***.

Comment: @jww: Doesn't matter if it's BIOS or EFI or OFW. The point is that the value is _obtained from_ firmware, rather than set up to be sent to the firmware.

Comment: Edited to reduce misinterpretations.

Comment: Thanks again @Hydranix. Trying to use the scaling value is producing horrible results. They are totally disconnected from the advertised CPU speed these processors are sold under. Even ***`scaling_max_freq`*** makes no sense. To make matters worse, there's no man page for ***`cpuinfo`*** or ***`cpufreq`***, so I'm not sure how the value is supposed to be used. All my searching leads back to, "just do X and use scaling factor" (and the scaling factor is not explained).

Comment: cpufreq - https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/