# Why does cpupower report different speeds and settings depending on if I'm root?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, performance

On debian 11, running cpupower gives different current CPU frequency if I run it as root vs a regular user

Running as root, I see the CPU set at 3.4ghz:

```
debian@dowest:~$ sudo cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.40 GHz, 3.40 GHz, 3.20 GHz, 3.00 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 3.40 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Running as a regular user, everything is identical except the current CPU line (returns two lines):

```
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 4.50 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
```

Looking in /proc/cpuinfo I see the 4500mhz:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 10
microcode   : 0xf0
cpu MHz     : 4498.984
```

However, using turbostat I see Bzy_MHz as 4500, and TSC_MHz as 3400, making me even more confused. (snipped a lot of the output):

```
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IRQ
-   -   65  1.45    4500    3408    61404
0   0   92  2.05    4500    3408    5193
```

So the question is. What speed is the processor running at? And if I wanted to lock it to the higher frequency (4500) at all times, how would I do that?

Comment: Because the CPU is scaling up and down based on load? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling Run something super CPU intensive it will be at the same value in all three situations

Comment: You do not want to lock the CPU. That wouldn't make sense. The CPU knows when to scale up or down and it does it quite a bit faster than you can think.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be based on scaling, there's no load currently, and they both report the same info over multiple requests.

From what I can see in the frequency governor, it should scale in ~10us, which is a bit slow on these servers.  We're running in an environment that requires extremely low latency, but gapped by long periods of idle.  Our application tries to return results in under 50us when prompted, so 10us of low-frequency is a +20% delay on results...

Comment: but what happens if you make sure it has 100% load? https://superuser.com/questions/1032357/why-is-current-cpu-frequency-read-only-for-root is also worth reading

Comment: My guess is that your user cannot query APCI information for the system so it cannot determine the current degree of scale, but root can. all the user can tell is the generic capabilities the OS stores on the hardware, not its current runtime information.

Comment: Oddly, the user version looks to be _more_ correct than the root version.  From another box (with governor set to performance and min/max both set to 3.20ghz).  Root sees: "current policy: frequency should be within 3.20 GHz and 3.20 GHz.", and "  current CPU frequency: 3.20 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)".  But user sees the same "3.20 to 3.20" but fluctuating frequency, such as: "current CPU frequency: 2.44 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)".  User version looks to match /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq (which I'd expect to be locked at 3.2ghz)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1032357/why-is-current-cpu-frequency-read-only-for-root
does look to explain what I'm seeing.  Looks like cpupower probably tries to read the hardware version (permission denied) and falls back to the scaling version.  Thanks!